# Required XMLGregorianCalendar date and time in e.g. 2012-06-08T08:16:43+00:00 format (according to the W3C guidelines)

Tags: java

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(d); //yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
convertStringToXmlGregorian(formattedDate);

public XMLGregorianCalendar convertStringToXmlGregorian(String dateString) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
        GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        gc.setTime(date);
        try {
            xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Optimize exception handling
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return xmlCal;
}
```

1. I GET folowing output:
 2014-06-12T20:19:05.000+05:30
1. i want xmlCal to return date in as 2014-06-12T08:16:43+00:00

Answer (score 1):

Your `GregorianCalendar` is in your system time zone. All you need is:

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC");
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(utc);
```

Having said that, it's not clear why you're converting a date to a string, then parsing it, then reformatting it. Also, you're formatting with a `T` in the pattern, and then parsing it without a `T` in the pattern - that's not going to work. I suspect the code you've given isn't the code you've actually got.

Are you always trying to create an `XMLGregorianCalendar` for the current date and time? Why not just skip the format/parse part?

(I'd also *strongly* advise against the exception handling code you've got.)

Comment: actually i am a fresher :) and got code from one of the link have tried with below code but still output is not correct:TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC");
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(utc);
System.out.print("gc: "+gc);

try {
 XMLGregorianCalendar xc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
  System.out.print("xc: "+xc);
} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
}

Comment: @user3734419: "is not correct" tells us basically nothing about what's going wrong. The code I've given you *will* provide you a date/time value in UTC rather than in your system local time zone.

Comment: i want time date and time in 2014-06-12T08:16:43+00:00

Comment: @user3734419: And what does the code I've provided give you? (Note that 2014-06-12T20:19:05.000+05:30 and 2014-06-12T08:16:43+00:00 are entirely different points in time...)

Comment: tried with below code the lines you have provided and then XMLGregorianCalendar xc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc); i has given me output as 2014-06-12T15:07:49.777Z

Comment: @user3734419: Right, so "Z" is equivalent to "+00:00", and it's giving you the current date and time. If you want a different date and time, that's got to come from somewhere. If you're just bothered about Z vs +00:00, as you sure you ought to be?

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24187516/642706) is correct.

The format you desire is defined by the [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt).

In Java you have your choice of two good date-time libraries that use ISO 8601 by default for generating and parsing strings: [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and java.time package new in Java 8.

Here is example code in Joda-Time. Obviously this code is much shorter and simpler than the code in the Question.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(); // simulating getting a Date object from somewhere else.
String output = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString(); // Converting a java.util.Date object to a Joda-Time DateTime object.
```

That string may end in a `Z` which stands for `Zulu` and means a zero offset from UTC, `00:00:00`. The use of `Z` is common and is compliant with the standards mentioned above.

If you want India time, specify an Indian time zone.

```
String outputKolkata = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ).toString(); // Converting a java.util.Date object to a Joda-Time DateTime object.
```

Comment: it is giving me '2014-06-13T05:09:10.421Z' as output. I need it as '2014-06-13T05:09:10+05:30' as XMLGregorianCalendar

Comment: @user3734419 Your Question says the opposite of your comment: `i want xmlCal to return date in as 2014-06-12T08:16:43+00:00`. Whichever is your intention, see the code I added to the bottom of my answer. Switching between time zones is easy and clear in Joda-Time.

Comment: sorry, but this did not helped. I think java 6 (which I am using) is not having an option to convert Date/String to XMLGregorianCalendar. Have also tried with Joda API but did not helped.